# C++ - Error C2065 - undecleared identifier

Tags: c++

I tired following some tutorials about C++ and I have got an error, there is about 4 in total but all about the same thing.

`Error  3   error C2065: 'end1' : undeclared identifier c:\users\*******\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project2\project2\main.cpp   25  1   Project2`

There is also another one

```
4   IntelliSense: identifier "end1" is undefined    c:\Users\********\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project2\Project2\Main.cpp  23  13  Project2
```

There was quite a bit of code so I put it on pastebin, [code](http://pastebin.com/0iFfptC1)

Thank you!:)

Comment: I guess copying from Youtube C++ tutorials highlights the need for good coding fonts. Or maybe 3D, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: I will be looking more carefully in the future

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `end1` is supposed to be [`endl`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/).

`endl` (end-line) inserts a newline character in the output buffer - you seem to have mistyped that as `end1` (end-one).

Comment: Thank you, spot on! Highly appreciate it. Need to look carefully while copying. I followed a video as I normally learn better from watching than reading. Thank you.